# Использование WebBrowser

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Предо мной стоит следующая задача:
Мне необходимо отобразить в WebBrowser обучающие курсы, находящиеся на DVD и представленные в виде html страницы, которая загружает скрипты, медиа и другие файлы. Изначально они находятся в зашифрованном виде, затем я должен их дешифровать и разместить их в оперативной памяти(т.е. размещать на винчестере их нельзя). Возможно ли передать WebBrowser непосредственно html код, который бы загружал эти обучающие курсы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте свойство DocumentText у компонента WebBrowser. Расшифруйте файл с главной страницей и его html-код поместите в это свойство. После этого у Вас инициализируется свойство Document, представляющее собой объектную модель html-документа. Через эту объектную модель Вы сможете добавлять ресурсы к документу.

Comment: @grotsun Для комментариев правильно использовать комментарии.

Answer (score 2):

Да, возможно. Я бы создал приложение WPF, которому передавал в командной строке путь к html-файлу. В библиотеке WPF существует специальный класс WebBrowser, который является движком IE. Данный класс отобразит вашу html-страницу.

Comment: И этот же движок даст сохранить эту страницу